# Notification icon that looks like "C" with a dot in the center on Xiaomi device

Tags: xiaomi, notification-icons

I have a Xiaomi device and am confused about this icon ("C" with a dot in the center).

[image]

I can't get what application this thing is.

Answer (score 0):

It's the repeated alarm. Just turn it off.